# Tell connected devices that this network does not offer internet access

Tags: networking, isc-dhcp

I installed the isc-dhcp-server (version 4.3.3) onto my Raspberry Pi and set it up to assign IP Addresses to devices that are connected to the Ethernet port (via a Switch but that should be unrelated).
This network is only for Ethernet purposes and it does not offer Internet access. But if I connect a PC to that Ethernet connection, it will sometimes try to load pages using the Ethernet connection instead of the WiFi network the PC is connected to.

**Is there a way to make the DHCP server tell connected devices that there is no Internet connection (or to just make the PC skip that connection when trying to load something)?**

EDIT:
For reference, this is my current `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
authoriatative;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.250;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    option domain-name "local";
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

Comment: omitting the router could help.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks, this answer turned out to be correct. I now accepted the answer given by Alexander T, but I'd actually would give you the reputation if I somehow could, because you answered it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `option routers 192.168.1.1;` entry from configuration. With this option, you set default gateway with DHCP lease. Without this option, your packets to Internet will come trough another default gateway(e.g. Wi-Fi).